# Authenticate with Google OAUTH2 but Authorize with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, google-oauth

I have a requirement to configure Tomcat, 9.x in my case, to Authenticate with a 3rd party system yet Authorize using a local db. My first remote Authenticator is Google OAUTH2. If and when I get it working I'll move on to Microsoft and possibly others. I think I have the Authentication step working. Since when I click on my Login With Google button I'm redirected by my servlet to a Google URL where it asks me for my Google credentials and then I'm redirected back to the URL that I specified. However, I see that the request.getRemoteUser() is null, which I'm guessing is due to the fact that the Authorization has not been performed. So my question is how do I configure Tomcat to do Authorization only and work with Google OAUTH2 to perform the Authentication.

Here's what I have so far:

WEB.XML

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <realm-name>Test Application</realm-name>
      <form-login-config>
         <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>

   <security-role>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
   </security-role>
```

Login.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(cmdToPerform) {
   document.getElementById("srcButon").value = cmdToPerform;
   document.getElementById("inpForm").submit(); 
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.clickableBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.clickableBtn:active {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
</style>
<title>Select Auth Provider</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 style="color: blue;">Please Choose your Login Method</h2>

<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ProcessAuthenticate" id="inpForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="srcButon" id="srcButon">

<button class="clickableBtn" onclick="submitForm('google')">
   <img alt="Login with Google" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LoginWGoogle.png">
</button>

</form>
```

ProcessAuthenticate.java

```
         response.sendRedirect("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?"+
               "scope=openid%20email&"+
               "access_type=offline&"+
               "include_granted_scopes=true&"+
               "response_type=code&"+
               "state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&"+
               "redirect_uri=https%3A//hockeytown.com/jsp/LandingPage.jsp&"+
               "client_id=my_client_id");      }
```

Thank you in advance for any and all assistance.